# Parsing a sentence with a causative verb

Tags: verbs, infinitives, syntactic-analysis, causative-verbs

I am an ESL teacher trying to help a student prepare for a test that will have a lot of sentence parsing. We are both stumped by the second verb in causative sentences. For example:

She asked the child to read a book.
She made her dog take a bath.

I've read that both the verbs "to read" and "take" are infinitives--the "take" is just a "bare infinitive." But how do you parse these verbs? To me, they seem like adverbial infinitive clauses, modifying the main verbs "asked" and "made." But other sources say that they are actually infinitive phrases acting as objects of those verbs.

I know there are similar questions on this website, but I appreciate your patience in explaining this phenomenon to me again. I didn't totally understand the reasoning behind the other examples.

THank you!

Comment: A related question has gone unanswered at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392936/diagramming-a-sentence-with-a-causative-verb.

Comment: Might have more luck on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com). A search for "causative verb" on there gets a few results that might be helpful.

Comment: Study 'control verbs' and 'raising verbs'.

Comment: Pehaps I am repeating the verb form advice in the other comments, but I want to point out (IMO) that the issue is not "take" or "read" but the verb "made" .   "She asked the child to take a bath" works fine.  "She told her dog to take the ball to Dad" ..it is the use of 'made' that I think needs examination

Comment: From what I can tell , the issue is that certain verbs require use of the "zero infinitive" https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/

Comment: They are catenative constructions. "Ask" and "made" are catenative verbs and the infinitival clauses "to read a book" and "take a bath" are their respective catenative complements (**not** modifiers or objects). The intervening NPs "the child" and "her dog" are the syntactic objects of "ask" and "made" and the _understood_ subjects of the infinitival clauses. The term 'catenative comes from the Latin word for "chain", and is appropriate here since the verbs concerned form a chain.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! This is very helpful, and now I know where to start looking. :)